# there is something wrong with my appcompat version

Tags: android, version-control, compilation

I don't really understand why my appcompat version is not accepted
Please help

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0aTE.png)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a warning, your app will still run.**

One or more of your transitive dependencies is requesting different version of of the Android Support Library that you are not requesting directly yourself, resulting in this conflict. You will need to run a Gradle dependency report and find out what is causing the problem, then manually request those artifacts yourself with your desired version (presently, 27.0.1).

**I think in  your case facebook is using old version, you should try updating facebook dependency version to latest.**

You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42374151/6891563) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have probabelly some libraries that use older versions of some others *support* libraries (not especially AppCompat), so you have to override them manually in the gradle to get rid of this warning.

You have to repeat this **until** the warning disapear :

- When you see the hint, copy and past the library and update the version number : for example if in the hint you have

> "blablabla... example include blablabla...
>   com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.1"

Add this to the dependencies section of the build.gradle script :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'
```